# appwrite realtime event handler never triggered

Tags: appwrite

I'm trying some basic example with appwrite self-hosted using a react component as client.
I'm not able to get realtime events.
From network panel, websoket's tab in chrome, I'm able to see only the initial messages

`{"type":"connected","data":{"channels":["databases.test.collections.*.documents"],"user":null}}`

But then, changing something in any documents in any collections in 'test' database I'm not getting any other message.

Here is the react component I'm using:

```
const [events, setEvents] = useState([]);
const {appwriteEnv} = props;

useEffect(async() => {
    
    const client = await new Client()
        .setEndpoint(appwriteEnv.endpoint) 
        .setProject(appwriteEnv.projectID);

    const unsubscribe = client?.subscribe("databases.test.collections.*.documents", response => {            
            setEvents([response.payload, ...events]);
        }
    );

    return () => {
        unsubscribe ? unsubscribe() : null
    }
}, [appwriteEnv])

return <>
    <pre>{JSON.stringify(events, null, 2)}</pre>
</>;
```

I tried to edit, add, delete documents in test databases, any collection, but I'm not getting messages from websocket.
All collections has persmission Any for read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wildcards are not supported for realtime channels. You should probably use `documents` instead.

See the Appwrite [docs](https://appwrite.io/docs/realtime#channels) for more details on supported channels.